# refining types with modules and typeclasses

Tags: coq

I'm not very familiar with modules or typeclasses in Coq, but based on my basic understanding of them, I believe I have a problem where I should use them.

I want to define a `sum` function that adds all the elements of a polymorphic `list t`. It should only work when the type of elements of the list (`t`) has some definition for `plus_function` and `plus_id_element`. The definition of `sum` I'd like to write would be something like this:

```
Fixpoint sum {t : Type} (l : list t) :=
  match l with
  | Nil => plus_id_element t
  | Cons x xs => ((plus_function t) x (sum xs))
  end.
```

I don't know what's the usual way to achieve something like this in Coq. I believe in Idris, for example, one would replace `t` by an interface/typeclass that defines `plus_function` and `plus_id_element`. Although typeclasses exist in Coq, I haven't seen them used very often and I believe people usually use modules instead to achieve something similar. I'm not sure if I'm mixing unrelated concepts. Are modules and typeclasses useful for this problem? What would be the recommended approach?

Comment: This question was discussed to some extent in [this Coq Club thread](https://sympa.inria.fr/sympa/arc/coq-club/2015-05/msg00163.html) and [this wiki post](https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/ModulesNotRecords) is somewhat related.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed typeclasses were designed for this exact task, but then you face the hard problem of designing the particular class hierarchy that will fit your problem well.

Coq doesn't provide a standard hierarchy of mathematical operators, and there are many delicate trade-offs in building one with regard to the choice of classes, operators, and axioms.

I thus recommend starting from a mature development such as the MathComp library. MathComp is based on "Canonical Structures" which are a similar notion to type classes, and provides quite a few ready to use classes. The [*Packaging Mathematical Structures*](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00368403v1/document)" paper contains more details, but the basic idea is that types pack their operators. For example, if you want to reason about abelian modules you can use the `zmodType` structure:

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect all_algebra.

Open Scope ring_scope.
Definition sum (A: zmodType) (s : seq A) := foldr +%R 0 s.
```

to define the sum over a list of elements of the abelian group `A`. Even better, don't define you own `sum` operator and just use the one provided by the library: `\sum_(x <- s) x`:

```
Lemma eq_sum (A: zmodType) (s : seq A) : sum s = \sum_(x <- s) x.
Proof. by rewrite unlock. Qed.
```

Comment: `sum` should be defined via right fold for the proof of `eq_sum` to go through, right?

Comment: oh indeed thanks, I had it like that in my local version, but somehow I didn't update properly when doing the edit.